# 30 W 220 V solder - How to run on 110V?

Tags: voltage

I mistakenly ordered a 220V 30W solder from ebay. In order to use it in USA, how do I design a voltage doubler circuit? I know sometime it is not worthwhile, but still want to do it for learning purposes.

Comment: Plan A: Get the right soldering iron and sell this one on ebay.  Plan B: Get a 1:2 stepup transformer.

Comment: Plan C (more challenging) find a seller of parts and order the 110v 30W element...

Comment: understood. I saw this circuit diagram..out of curiosity, should I even try? https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/j4whe2/use-220v-soldering-iron-with-110-v-ac/

Comment: 1: Don't play with mains power. 2: Check the maximum reverse voltage for the diodes or use more appropriate ones. 3: You should calculate the required capacitance,  output voltage, etc - because the author doesn't show those calculations anywhere, and you have a 30 W iron. 4: You could use a simpler voltage doubler instead. 5: Don't play with main electricity, it's dangerous stuff.

Comment: @marcKatz no, you should *not* even try. see point 1 from Oskar, and more importantly, his point 5.

Comment: Hey, if you were willing to risk your life and were desperately poor you could salvage a microwave oven transformer, cut off the high voltage secondary and replace it with a ~120V secondary which you would put in series with the primary to get 240V. It would probably take around 120 turns of wire to get that voltage (you could wrap few on and measure then wind based on that). But don't do that, you are not poor and you should go buy a proper safe soldering iron WITH UL approval (!) and use that. Your circuits and life insurance will thank you. Trial lawyers will be angry.

Comment: Besides the high risk of electric shock, the given circuit will not produce 220V AC, but 310V DC, which is 1.4 times bigger and this way the soldering iron power would be 2 times higher than nominal - 60W instead of 30W. The heater element will burn very quickly - from minutes to couple of hours at best. Also the author of this schematic should have changed the model of the diodes - with 4148 it will burn like a popcorn.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov:  That's if the capacitance is large enough to maintain the voltage for a long period.  It's also possible that the capacitance is too low and the voltage doubler never gets charged up.

Answer (score 1):

That circuit is called a "transformer", and you wouldn't build it, you'd buy it.

Yes, it's absolutely not feasible financially to build or buy one just to run a $10 soldering iron, but it's really just two runs of cable wound around the same iron core. One side has twice as many windings as the other – that's the side with twice as much voltage.

Of course, modern transformers that you can buy have very cleverly designed iron cores to minimize losses, they're very diligently wound and isolated, encased and contacted, but the basic principle is that both sides are electromagnets: the primary side converts an alternating current to a time-changing magnetic field, and the other converts a time-changing magnetic field to an alternating current.

The wikipedia article on [transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) will be of interest to you.

Comment: The ones for converting mains appliances are usually autotransformers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer